# Laravel delete row with no 'id'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel to create a small app. This app uses a remote database. This database doesn't have an AI id. So when I try to delete a row from the datbase (which I selected with the 'where::' function) I get the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `mailbox` where `id` is null)
```

Is there a possibility to delete a row with using another key than the primary id?

Comment: At the model try set `public $primary = null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a primary key, set it in your model with

```
protected $primaryKey = 'my_PK';
```

If you don't have any PK, use a custom query:

```
$q = 'DELETE FROM my_table where my_field = ?'
\DB::delete($q, [$my_data]);
```

Comment: It will replace the `?`

Answer (score 8):

If you have a Model for your table, you can use something like:

```
Model::where('column', $value)->delete();
```

Where `Model` is the name of your model, etc. You don't need to write the entire query yourself. You can Eloquent to make the delete query as complex as you need (i.e. multiple `where` queries).

Answer (score 0):

Just don`t delete model!

```
protected $primaryKey = 'custom_id';
  
$model = Model::where('id', $id);

// No. It will delete all records with equals $model->custom_id for this model.
$model->delete(); 

// Yes. Delete only this one record.
Model::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Model update() the same problem!

Answer (score -1):

Use a new query instead of the instance you selected.
For example:

```
// logs table do not have a primary key
$log = Log::where('a',123)->first();
//do not:
$log->delete();
//try this:
Log::where('a',123)->delete();
```